# Isoenthalpic-isobaric ensemble

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, pressure, terminology

Does the isoenthalpic-isobaric ensemble (also called the *NPH ensemble*) represent a system capable of exchanging only pressure-volume work with a barostat, but no heat with a heat bath or particles with a reservoir?
And if not, what would be a name (and the "acronym") for such ensemble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $N,P,H=const.$, we have

$$dH = \delta Q - VdP + \mu dN = \delta Q = 0$$

since both $dH$, $dP$ and $dN$ are zero. This means indeed that the system does not exchange heat, but only isobaric work with the reservoir:

$$dU = -P dV$$

In some way, we can think of our system as an adiabatic, impermeable "balloon" of variable volume in a constant-pressure environment.